# Close firefox if it is inactive or idle?

Tags: firefox, window

Is there any way to shut down firefox if it is inactive? Some addtional tool or addon ? Or way?

Comment: Do you mean, if you go away for 20 minutes or so, that Firefox shuts itself down automatically? Why not just shut it down yourself or leave it on?

Comment: Just out of interest: Why do you need this? What's the harm of just keeping FF running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your screen saver to 20 minutes or whatever you want, then instead of the normal screensaver just have it call pskill with the name firefox in the command line http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx

Comment: which screensaver?

Comment: Related info: [Run a batch/cmd upon screensaver](http://superuser.com/questions/538146/run-a-batch-cmd-upon-screensaver)

Answer (score 2):

Auto Shutdown: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5452/

Comment: What did you put in the idle script to shut down firefox?

Answer (score 2):

There's a neat FF extension that's designed to enable a 'Kiosk' mode in firefox, with an idle-out feature, and more:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mkiosk/

Comment: mKiosk does only reset the session. It doesn't close Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly solving this problem as it seems like an overkill, but just a curious find...

[Auto Close Idle](http://autocloseidle.com/) is a program that monitors selected users' programs and closes them when certain amount of inactivity has been detected. Unfortunately, it is a commercial product and pretty expensive as it's intended to be used in domain environment, mainly to help reduce the amount of floating licenses needed.

Comment: this is way too much !!!