# Log screensaver activity

Tags: windows-7, screensaver, event-log

I'd like to know if there's any way to see logs of the screensaver activity. Something like that:

```
02/02/2013 10:16:47 Screensaver started
02/02/2013 10:17:23 Screensaver stopped
```

I'm running Win7 Home premium 64 with ElectricSheep screensaver.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to know if there's any way to see logs of the screensaver activity.

Yes there is! However screensaver invoking and dismissal (event IDs 4802 and 4803 respectively) aren't events that are normally logged by default, and so you need to turn auditing/logging of those events on first using the **Group Policy Editor**:

[image: 1]

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/538849/138343) for more details.

---

Edit: Since you're using Win7 Home Premium which doesn't include the Group Policy Editor, I tried using Process Monitor to figure out exactly which registry keys were being modified when auditing for these events is enabled/disabled. Unfortunately there were just too many changes being made and even after filtering I was unable to narrow it down sufficiently. Perhaps someone can help with this information, but if it's not possible the next best thing might be to just follow the instructions in this [How to Enable “Group Policy Editor” (gpedit.msc) in Windows 7 Home Premium, Home Basic and Starter Editions?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions) article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's exactly what i'm looking for but indeed I don't have gpedit so I tried to install it with your link but when I run it it says "MMC could not create the snap-in." I also tried the fix for it also in the link with no avail.. I was looking for the registry entry too

Comment: Did you follow Note 1 and copy the folders and MSC file? Does your username contain spaces? Did you add the quotes wherever required to the x64 (not x86) batch file and run it? Did you try running the program as admin? Beyond this right now I'm unable to help unfortunately, but if I find some info about the registry edits I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I did exactly all of the above except running as admin which I just tried and doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the System Event Viewer. You can get to it by going to *Start, Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Event Viewer*.

Comment: I already looked there with no luck..

ps:why did you edit the question?

Comment: @pocpoc47: No need to append your name or add a signature to questions or answers here (read the FAQ). This isn't a forum, and if you want to add some info about yourself [edit your About Me page on your profile](http://superuser.com/users/edit/213606). Your last sentence was superfluous too. You can always check exactly what edits were made by clicking on the "x hours ago" link, and rollback if required (although in this case keep in mind the edits were made by a diamond mod).

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I'm new in here :) Thanks for your help

Comment: I believe there are some key loggers (which I am not much a fan of) but I think I had one once that could track the screen saver. this was back in xp days though.