# Automatically running a windows bat file after returning from idle

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-task-scheduler

First off, the background on what I want to do:

I am running rosetta@home on my computers at home and work, and I often find minirosetta tasks stuck in memory when I resume using the computer after a long idle period. I haven't found any real solution to the problem so I am looking for a workaround solution that involves automatically killing the minirosetta tasks when I return from an idle state.

It is possible to kill tasks with a simple command line (in windows7):

taskkill /IM taskname.exe /F

So I am looking for a way to execute a batch script to kill minirosetta tasks when I return from idle mode. Does anyone know if I can use one of the event triggers under windows task scheduler to automatically run a bat file after returning from idle? I see many different possibilities for event triggers but no idea what to use for returning from idle.

Alternatively I could run an executable or bat file when idle, and this executable could wait for mouse/keyboard action before it runs a script to kill the minirosetta tasks. Is this possible with simple scripts or do I need to compile a windows exec?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming when you return after leaving the PC idle for a while you find the screensaver running and dismiss it using the mouse or keyboard. So one possible solution would be to execute your batch file (or even *taskkill* directly) on screensaver dismissal.

[**Event ID 4803**](http://eventopedia.cloudapp.net/default.aspx?LogType=Windows+Event+Log&LogName=Security&OSVersion=6&Category=Logon%2fLogoff&Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing&TaskCategory=Other+Logon%2fLogoff+Events&EventID=4803&action=go) corresponds to **The screen saver was dismissed**, so all you need to do is turn on logging of this event using the **Local Group Policy Editor** and then use **Task Scheduler** to create a task that will be launched when the event occurs. You can find a detailed tutorial for this [here](https://superuser.com/a/538849/138343).

Comment: wow, awesome exactly what I was looking for!  thank you so much

Comment: well, shucks i only have win7 home premium, so cannot run the local group policy editor.  is there any registry hack i can do to enable logging of event 4803?

Comment: The official docs state that "Audit Policy security settings are not registry keys", and the [Group Policy Search site](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net) didn't return anything. I think you're out of luck unless [this](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/) works for you, but I've never tried it.

Comment: interesting, thanks again!  and i was about to try learning and writing python!   maybe i still will, working the win api through python seems like it would be convenient

Comment: Did this finally worked? I'm curious because I also want to run a command (to stop an online backup service) once I return to using my computer.

Comment: @Chuim: If you have Group Policy Editor there's no reason it won't work.

Comment: @Karan: thanks for getting back on this and yes it did totally work for me! :)