# What 'wait for idle for' as 'do not wait' means?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

There is already a question asking [Task scheduler - What is "Wait for idle for"?](https://superuser.com/questions/777488/task-scheduler-what-is-wait-for-idle-for), but I could not understand what the `Do not wait` thing does when `Start the task only if the computer is idle for` is set to something as `10 minutes`.

[image]

I have set the trigger action as `On idle, When the computer is idle`.

[image]

[image]

What will happen when the `Wait for idle for` is set to `Do not wait` and `Start the task only if the computer is idle for` is set to something as `10 minutes`? Will the task never start because I set `Do not wait`? What `Do not wait` mean? Do not wait what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iddle settings in "Conditions" work with any kind of trigger, not just `on iddle`.

When the trigger fires:
Task Scheduler (TS) checks if the computer has been, up to this moment, in an iddle state for 10 min (per your setting).

- If yes, then it will run the task - regardless of what is inside the "*Wait for idle for*" box.
- If no, then it will wait for the condition "computer has been in iddle state for 10 min" to become true - and will wait for up to an amount set in the... "*Wait for idle for* " box. If in that box is `Do not wait` then... it will not wait at all! but instead will call  it quits and not run the task for this instance/firing of trigger.
  It will try to run it next time the trigger will fire.
  If that trigger happens to be set "On iddle", then the new firing can happen no sooner than 15min later, because TS only checks whether computer is in idle state every 15 min.

Now `goto "When the trigger fires:"`.