# Disable ability for specific users to lock computer Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-users, fast-user-switching

I am trying to make it so that specific users cannot remain logged in while not on the computer.  I know I can kill their session through Task manager, but is there a way to force them to log off vice Lock to save the trouble of going to the Task manager every time?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to clarify if this is a standalone/workgroup computer or on a domain.

Comment: Place them in a specific user group, then remove the ability to lock the computer, from that user group.  You can basically only give the user the option to log out, and if they just let their session sit there, automatically log them out after a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at different angle, you can [logoff users](https://windowsadmin-scripts.blogspot.com/2009/04/logoff-remote-users-and-administrators.html) upon [screensaver](https://superuser.com/questions/538146/run-a-batch-cmd-upon-screensaver).

Comment: please include the details of both links in your answer