# Hook task scheduler trigger into display off/on event

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I want to putting a logging event on when my display is wakes and goes to sleep. I haven't found anything on the internet speaking on this event specifically. How do I hook into this event?

[image: Turn off display after]

Comment: I don't think its possible. There are no events logged in the eventlog when this happens which could be a trigger. You could create a trigger that activates when the computer is idle, but you can't delay the task, so its useless. Besides it doesn't actually monitor if the screen went into suspension.

Comment: Just an update, I am still working toward hooking into this event, but what I did in the meanwhile is hook into the screensaver event, using the method described in this answer, #3 no third party tools. 
https://superuser.com/questions/538146/run-a-batch-cmd-upon-screensaver